# Can I create GUI without "extends"

Tags: scala, scala-swing

I start to learn Scala and I confused. Can I create GUI without "extends SimpleSwingApplication" or "SimpleGUIApplication" or may be something yet? I try to do it so:

```
import scala.swing._

object Main {
def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {
    val frame = new Frame   {title = "test GUI"}
    val button = new Button {text = "test button"}
    val uslPanel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
        contents += button
        }
    //listenTo(button)

    frame.contents_=(uslPanel)
    frame.visible_=(true)
    }
}
```

It works, but if only "listenTo(botton)" is commented. How can I use "listenTo(...)" without "extends SimpleGui... etc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that the swing application traits give you. (1) they defer the initial code to the event dispatch thread (cf. [Swing's Threading Policy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/package-summary.html#threading), also [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)). (2) They inherit the `Reactor` trait which gives you the `listenTo` method that you are now missing.

I think you should just mix in the `SwingApplication` application trait, that's the easiest. Otherwise, you can do these things by hand:

```
import scala.swing._

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    Swing.onEDT(initGUI) // Scala equivalent of Java's SwingUtilities.invokeLater
  }

  def initGUI() {
    val frame  = new Frame  { title = "test GUI"    }
    val button = new Button { text  = "test button" }
    val uslPanel = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
      contents += button
    }
    val r = new Reactor {}
    r.listenTo(button)
    r.reactions += {
      case event.ButtonClicked(_) => println("Clicked")
    }

    frame.contents = uslPanel
    frame.visible  = true  // or use `frame.open()`
  }
}
```

Note that every widget in Scala-Swing inherits `Reactor`, so you often find this style:

```
    val button = new Button {
      text = "test button"
      listenTo(this) // `listenTo` is defined on Button because Button is a Reactor
      reactions += { // `reactions` as well
        case event.ButtonClicked(_) => println("Clicked")
      }
    }
```